# Printing out users without /home directories and /home directories without users

Tags: linux, directory, users, perl

I need to develop a perl script that will generate a formatted listing of
any user without a `home` directory and any `home` directory that is not attached to a user.
For example, if I used the script below to read in the systems users how would I print out which users do not have a home directory based on theirs `UID`:

```
open (USERS, '-|' , 'getent passwd' ) or die $!;
    @passwd_entries = <USERS>;
    close USERS;
```

And if I read in the system's home directories with the script below how would I print out which directories do not have users attached to them?

```
open (HOMES, '-|' , 'ls /home' ) or die $!;
    @home_dirs = <HOMES>;
    close HOMES;
```

Comment: Is it an assumption, then, that every home directory is under /home? Root’s commonly is not.

Comment: Yes that’s the assumption, all the home directories I’m working with are under /home

Comment: The code in the question generates two arrays the first one with all the users and the second one with all the directories. For the users array how do I print out the entries without /home directories and for the /home array how do I print out the directories without users. I would assume that UID's in the passwd file will have something to do with generating the appropriate results. I just don't know how

Answer (score 1):

If you're happy with a `bash` solution, this will write out the list of users without home directories in `/home`, and the directories under `/home` that have no users in the password database:

```
comm -3 <(getent passwd | cut -d: -f6 | sort -u) <(ls -d1 /home/*)
```

Answer (score 0):

It has been a while since I have been using Perl, but I came up with something that may get you where you need to go.  Since you are using Perl, we will avoid using any `bash` commands:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

# this will get all users and homedirs directly
while(my ($name,$passwd,$uid,$gid,$quota,$comment,$gcos,$dir,$shell) = getpwent()){
    my $dirstate;
    # this will check if $dir exists and is a directly
    if (-e $dir and -d $dir) {
        $dirstate = 'homeexists';
    } else {
        $dirstate = 'nohome';
    }

    # here you have knowledge of which home dirs do and do not exist in $dirstate
    print "$name:$uid:$gid:$gcos:$dir:$shell:$dirstate\n";
}
```

Or, if you really wanted to use bash commands, this one liner does close to the same:

```
getent passwd | awk -F: '{printf "%s %s\n",$1,$6}' | while read i; do home=($i); if [ ! -d ${home[1]} ]; then home+=("nohome") ; fi ; echo ${home[@]}; done
```

As for which home directories exist that do not have users, since home directories can be anywhere on the filesystem I am not sure how best to accomplish that.  You could use `ls` to see what is in `/home` and compare to the users you get from `getent`, if that is what you need to do.

Comment: open (HOMES, '-|' , 'ls /home' ) or die $!;
    @home_dirs = <HOMES>;
    close HOMES;     This saves all the /home directories I'll be analyzing in an array. How do I print out the once that don't have users?